# Create SharePoint list and fields in feature

Tags: xml, sharepoint, list

How can I create a new list via a feature in MOSS and also include new fields in that list?

I am currently using a  node to create the list but I want some new fields in addition to the title field that appears with a new custom list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [blog post](http://rnowik.com/MOSS-WSS-3-0-Creating-a-custom-list-feature.aspx) for a detailed answer (the section "Adding an extra field to our list feature" should be directly applicable). In a nutshell, the methodology provided in the SDK is incorrect and will now display additional fields in the default add/edit/new forms for the list.